# ImportError: cannot import name 'EXTRACTOR_FILENAME' from 'talon.signature'

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting an `import` statement to work. I am attempting to use this package:
https://github.com/mailgun/talon

I am running the following command:

```
from talon.signature import EXTRACTOR_FILENAME, EXTRACTOR_DATA
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'EXTRACTOR_FILENAME' from 'talon.signature' (system path to file)
```

While troubleshooting I don't see `EXTRACTOR_FILENAME` or `EXTRACTOR_DATA` defined anywhere. I did a search in directory for all files.  Is there some sort of convention in python where `EXTRACTOR_FILENAME` maps to a specific class?

UPDATE: Figured it out, just something as simple as manually defining the 2 constants. The docs weren't exactly clear or I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

For your project the import looks like this:

```
  import talon
  from talon import quotations
```

Put those statements on the top of your file, and it should work.
if you don't have the packages on your system type this in your terminal:

```
pip install talon
```

The Github repo also explains this

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. I get the same error pointing to EXTRACTOR_FILENAME. I don't know where to look to define EXTRACTOR_FILENAME.

Comment: could you please post your entire file? so I can look at all of your code.

Comment: I was just testing it from the command line, I installed the talon package above, was able to run some of the commands, such as from talon.signature.bruteforce import extract_signature, and then call the extract_signature function successfully.  Its when I try to just do: "from talon.signature import EXTRACTOR_FILENAME, EXTRACTOR_DATA" it gives me the error above in my post. thanks.